# Getting the energy levels of the Morse potential using perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, molecular-dynamics

$$v(r)=v_{0}(e^{-2(r-r_{e})/a}-2e^{-(r-r_{e})/a}) . $$
After expanding the Morse potential around $r_{e} $, i get:
$$v(r)=v_{0}(-1+\frac{(r-r_{e})^2}{a^{2}}-\frac{(r-r_{e})^3}{a^3}+\frac{7(r-r_{e})^4}{12a^{4}})$$
how do i get the energy levels of the Morse potential as a cubic and quartic correction to the harmonic approximation?

Comment: What aspect of perturbation theory are you confused about?

Comment: stationary perturbation theory , i know that the cubic correction in the second order perturbation is given by : $$ \frac{\hbar^{2}}{8\mu^{3}\omega_{e}^{4}}(30v^{2}+30v+11)$$ but still failed to get the energy levels as  : harmonic oscillator + $\hbar\omega_{e}\chi(v+\frac{1}{2})^{2}$